# MySQL query where not equal to string does not work in single column

Tags: mysql

A very very strange error. I have a MariaDB 10.5 (Docker) database with a user table.

**User Table**

| id | name | email | company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Dennis | dennis@xyemail.com | foo |
| P002 | David | david@xymail.com | bar |

I want all users who do not work in the company **foo**.

```
select * from user where company <> "foo"
select * from user where company != "foo"
```

I get no entry for both queries. On the other hand, if I want to have all users
who work in the company **foo**, I get them. The problem only occurs in the
company column. I don't know what the problem should be here. Because it is a
very simple request.

**That works**
`select * from user where company = "foo"`

**Workbench output**

```
10:48:35    SELECT email FROM t.ci_users where company != 'foo' LIMIT 0,
1000    0 row(s) returned   0,00095 sec / 0,000010 sec

10:49:42    SELECT email FROM t.ci_users where company = 'foo' LIMIT 0,
1000    1 row(s) returned   0,00042 sec / 0,0000060 sec
```

**Schema from company column**

Type: VARCHAR

Character_Set: utf8

Comment: Works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bd908179b4e2e8cc8d6112466a1f2aa8)

Comment: You should be using single quotes rather than double quotes in mysql to identify strings. (although double quotes will work) Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: And what happen if you use `select * from user where company  not in ('foo')` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha the same. Nothing :-(

Comment: @P.Salmon it tried with single quote and nothing. i will update my question and add the schema from this table.

Comment: @KrassVerpeilt it seems strange to me , I reproduced the example and it works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e20ac99a4283ec55802a6f5d7acecf34

Comment: @ErgestBasha for me too. Small note: I use MariaDB.

Comment: Remove `LIMIT 0` or change to `LIMIT 10` or something

Comment: @ErgestBasha Workbench add limit my query was the query in my question. I can´t understand why it doesnt work only in this one column??!?

Comment: I don't know why mysql accepts limit 0 but it does and as expected returns nothing at all. Are you confusing offset with limit which can start at zero I wonder? If so your query should be limit 0,1 to get the first (if you add an order by)

Comment: @P.Salmon I change Limit to 10 and 0,1 and nothing. I use a different query so as not to create a bottleneck here. But I would be interested to know why it behaves so strangely. And because it works for you, the error must be in my environment. But I don't even have an idea what the problem
could be 